# Prestashop 1.5.3 show custom page at startup

Tags: prestashop

I'd like to show a custom page at startup and provide a link to the 'real' shop in the menu.
How can I redirect prestashop to my custom page at startup?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that you can change the $default_controller in Dispatcher.php with any controller you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can tell Prestashop to show a custom page (at least without hacking around). But since everything works with modules, you can remove all the modules displayed by default, and add your own modules.